# Checking if first letter of a string = char

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I'm having a short 2 character string being sent from C++ to my Javascript (using Awesomium). I know for a fact that the string will either be "L1", "G1", "P1", or "D1". These are initials.

What I am trying to do is having a text div display the full name of the initial sent in, for example, if "L1" is sent, then "Limes" would appear on the screen, or if "G1" was sent in, "Grapes" would appear.

I've tried to remove the last character from the string, then check with if statements that the letter matches with one of the four. I then set the div's text using `$('#div').html("text to be inserted");`

For some reason, the code automatically displays the last if statement's contents, whether or not that is the correct string.

JS:

```
function showStats(job)
{
   $('#jobHat').css("hat-image", "url(images/"+job+"Hat.png)");

   var jobInitial = job.slice(0, -1); 
   if(jobInitial = "L")
   {
        $('#playerJobText').html("Landman");
   }
   if(jobInitial = "G")
   {
        $('#playerJobText').html("Geologist");
   }
   if(jobInitial = "P")
   {
        $('#playerJobText').html("Petroleum Engineer");
   }
   if(jobInitial = "D")
   {
        $('#playerJobText').html("Drilling Engineer");
   }
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="playerJobText"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#playerJobText
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align:center;
   top: 32.5%;
   left: 19%;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-style: normal;
   color: black;
   z-index: 50;
}
```

I include the `jobHat` segment in the JS code to show an area where the "L1", "G1", etc. string works as it should. The image file name is replaced by the string, which shows different images I have, as those images are named L1Hat.png, G1Hat.png, etc.

So what is wrong with the way I'm trying to check the first letter of the string to replace a div's text?

**EDIT** I had tried the double == and then the triple === but there was still no results. I put the single = in for this example as it's what I'm most familiar with, but I'm glad I did so I could get the reminder from you all that == or === is better for this occasion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you were *assigning* rather than *testing for equality*.

In any event, this code below is simpler and avoids a lot of repetition:

```
function showStats(job)
{
   $('#jobHat').css("hat-image", "url(images/"+job+"Hat.png)");

   var initial = job[0];  // or job.substring(0, 1);
   var title = ({
       L: 'Landman',
       G: 'Geologist',
       P: 'Petroleum Engineer',
       D: 'Drilling Engineer'
   })[initial];

   $('#playerJobText').text(title);
}
```

Comment: NB: note new parens now around the object literal in the code - Chrome appears to require them.

Comment: maybe it's just me. but this feels like a very indirect way of doing things.

Comment: @Pacerier How is it indirect? Please explain, I don't see.

Comment: @Briz it's not indirect, it's separation of data from logic

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, using **slice** here is a bad choice. use **charAt** instead.

Secondly, that 4 **if** statements is an eyesore. use **switch** instead.

```
function showStats(job){
    $('#jobHat').css("hat-image", "url(images/"+job+"Hat.png)");

    var full_name;
    switch(job.charAt(0)){
        case "L":
            full_name="Landman";
            break;
        case "G":
            full_name="Geologist";
            break;
        case "P":
            full_name="Petroleum Engineer";
            break;
        case "D":
            full_name="Drilling Engineer";
            break;
        default:
            throw "invalid input: "+input;
    }
    $('#playerJobText').html(full_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an assignment operator

```
if(jobInitial = "L")
```

should be

```
if(jobInitial === "L")
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are not comparing, but assigning. Use double `==` or triple `===`

Comment: I had actually tried both == and === and there was no change. :c But Alnitak figured out a working way. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: is it because you are missing the last **}** to close your function?